# $n\sum_{i=0}^{\lg(n)}(3/2)^i=n\frac{(3/2)^{\lg(n)}-1}{.5}$ doesn't hold for some situations, is my understanding correct?

Tags: summation, logarithms

I'm learning "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition
By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein", referencing the [solution](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eajl213/CLRS/Ch4.pdf) to Exercise 4.4-1

$$n\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lg(n)}(3/2)^i=n\frac{(3/2)^{\lg(n)}-1}{.5} \tag{1}$$

Does the right side of the equation above equal the following?

$$2n ((3/2) ^ {\lg(n)}-1) \tag{2}$$

If yes, the equation doesn't hold for some situations, e.g. $n=2$, is my understanding correct?

I guess to verify equation (1) is equivalent to verifying the following

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lg(n)}(3/2)^i=2((3/2)^{\lg(n)}-1) \tag{3}$$

let $n=2$, the left side of (3) equals $\dfrac{5}{2}$ while the right side doen't.

Actually, it seems equation (1) doesn't hold anyway, am I missing something?

Comment: The power on the right-hand side should be $\lg(n)+1$ and not $\lg(n)$. I belive it is a typo from the authors.

Comment: @Gary Thank you so much. I just verified the equation with your correction, it worked so well! Would you please give a few steps showing how to get $2((3/2)^{n+1}-1)$ from $\sum_{i=0}^n(3/2)^i$ ? I will gratefully accept the answer :)

Comment: It is just the summation formula for a geometric progression: $$
\sum\limits_{i = 0}^m {r^i }  = \frac{{r^{m+ 1}  - 1}}{{r - 1}}.
$$